# XSLT Need to count number of nodes where count is more than 1 within the parent node

Tags: xslt

Given the below simplified XML, I need to count the number of  nodes where there is more than 1  node under /root/a/. So even though there are a total of 8  nodes, the correct answer for me is 3 since the first and last /root/a have more than 1 , 3 total. The xslt I have here will just give me the value 8. I've looked at using keys, position function, etc. unsuccessfully... but I'm thinking there is probably simpler answers. Thanks for any help.

```
<root>
    <a>
        <b>
            <c>valuex</c>
        </b>
        <b>
            <c>valuey</c>
        </b>
    </a>
    <a>
        <b>
            <c>valuez</c>
        </b>
    </a>
    <a>
        <b>
            <c>valuex</c>
        </b>
    </a>
    <a>
        <b>
            <c>valuex</c>
        </b>
    </a>
    <a>
        <b>
            <c>valuex</c>
        </b>
        <b>
            <c>valuey</c>
        </b>
        <b>
            <c>valuey</c>
        </b>
    </a>
    <a>
    </a>
</root>
```

My stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="addCount">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="/root/a/b">
                    <xsl:value-of select="count(/root/a/b)"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="0"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="$addCount"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Why wouldn't the count of the `a` elements that have more than 1 children be 2? I don't understand why you think it would be 3, unless you want the max() value of the count of children of `a` elements that have more than 1 child?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mads. It's confusing. I actually need to count the number of <b> nodes that are more than 1. So the first <a> node has 2 <b>, which counts as 1. The 2nd, 3rd and 4th <a> have only 1 <b> so I don't count any of them. The 5th <a> has 3 <b>, so count as 2. 3 total.

Comment: And I can't just count all the <b> and subtract the <a>, because sometimes I may not have a <b> under the <a>

Comment: You said that the 1st and 5th a elements count as two, so the total is 3...huh? You can always add 1 to the count, but if there are two that meet your criteria, why is the count 3?

Comment: Okay, I think I understand. You want the count of `b` elements that are not the first child `b` element? So, of the two `a` elements that have more than one `b` element, there are 2 `b` elements in the first and 3 `b` elements in the fifth `a` element, for a grand total of 5, excluding the first `b` element from each, the desired count would be 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based upon your comment, it sounds as if you want to find the count of the `b` elements that are children of `/root/a` , but are not the first `b` element under each of the `a` elements.

You can use the following to select all of the `b` elements that are children of `/root/a` and exclude the first `b` from each set:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">  
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="count(/root/a/b[position() > 1])"/>        
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You could also use the following to obtain the count of all the `b` elements that have a `preceding-sibling` that is a `b` element:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">  
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="count(/root/a/b[preceding-sibling::b])"/>        
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I need! Thanks Mads!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your clarification correctly (and that's a big if!), you want to do:

```
<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:variable name="a" select="a[count(b) &gt; 1]" />
    <xsl:value-of select="count($a/b) - count($a)"/>        
</xsl:template>
```

which could be shortened to:

```
<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:value-of select="count(a/b[position() != 1])"/>   
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Yes, Micahel! This is what I need! Both your answer and Mads answer below work. Thanks!